# Save screenshot with current date time format,

Tags: python, selenium, screenshot

I am using selenium with python, I would like to save the screenshot in particular folder with current date time format, so that all the screenshots are saved with unique name

Can anyone help

Comment: What have you done to try to solve this? Stack Overflow is not the place to drop off your work for others to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current date and time. Next, you can save the screenshots by including `now` in the filename.

```
from datetime import datetime

# datetime object containing current date and time
now = datetime.now()

print("now =", now)

# dd/mm/YY H:M:S
dt_string = now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
print("date and time =", dt_string)
```

Comment: Have you correctly imported the 'date time' module?